# Form validating using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to validate form. I try to validate it using regexp. When I create event 'click' and bind it to button element, i've faced the problem. When I click on button element under email input shows a message
'Please enter a valid email address. And when I click second time value change to true, but initially value of email input is true(because I check it, below on screen you can see it).

```
    const form = document.querySelector('form')
    const emailRegexp = /^[\w.+\-]+@gmail\.com$/g;
    const usernameRegexp = /^\w+(?![\b])\w+$/g;
    const fail = document.querySelectorAll('div.input_failed');
    console.log(emailRegexp.test('fdjfvnjdknv@gmail.com'));

    styleButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        const testEmail = emailRegexp.test(input[0].value);
        if(testEmail) {
            fail[0].style.display = 'none';
            console.log(true);
        }
        else {
            fail[0].style.display = 'block';
            console.log(false);
        }
    });
```

```
    main.js:49 true
    main.js:59 false
    main.js:55 true
    main.js:59 false
    main.js:55 true
    main.js:59 false
    main.js:55 true
    main.js:59 false
    main.js:55 true
    main.js:59 false
    main.js:55 true
    main.js:59 false
    main.js:55 true
    main.js:59 false
```

I check the type of this two string and they are both string.Anyway the problem didn't solved. And I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Regex only for @gmail.com

```
var emailRegexp = new RegExp(/^[\w.+\-]+@gmail\.com$/,"g");
```

Regex for email validation

```
var emailRegexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
```

You can also test the regex here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: This regex is right. But I think the problem isn't in a regex. The problem in listener or in a function, I guess

Comment: Can you please share you code as text.